# SQL executable very slowly How can I speed up?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

(SQL Server) This code very slowly How can I speed up?

```
update g set g.Ebat=mtib.icerik_anlami  from #gecici g
left outer join database.dbo.table2 mtib on mtib.malzeme_kodu=g.malzeme_kodu
where mtib.alan_sabit_adi='ebat' and g.Ebat=mtib.icerik

update ga set ga.zemin_rengi=mtib.sira_no  from #gecici ga
left outer join database.dbo.table2 mtib on mtib.malzeme_kodu=ga.malzeme_kodu
where mtib.alan_sabit_adi='ZeminRengi' and ga.zemin_rengi=mtib.icerik

update gaa set gaa.bordur_rengi=mtib.sira_no  from #gecici gaa
left outer join database.dbo.table2 mtib on mtib.malzeme_kodu=gaa.malzeme_kodu
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? What does the explain/execution plan say?

Comment: This is too broad, what SQL technology are you using, what is your table structure, some sample data in your tables?  Did you check indexes?

Comment: when you run the queries separately, which one is more costly?

Comment: all the same -sql server

Comment: you are using mtib.icerik_anlami while updating the value anyway, maybe using an inner join instead of "left outer" is what you are looking for?

Comment: g is an alias table , you updating the hash table ? well how much of data thsi table is being inserted ?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, why did you add the <mysql> tag when OP says SQL Server?

Comment: @jarlh because he said (mysql) in the beginning of the question, still it says mysql. In the comments he said sql server I saw now. He does not know the difference maybe.

Comment: @ErayBalkanli, I see. Very confusing...

Comment: @michael, without more info, we can't help you.

Comment: Please include the execution plan in the question for each one of the queries, so we can take a look and advise accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use `LEFT JOIN` for your purpose. Try `INNER JOIN`. Also again you don't need to use WHERE all filters related with joined table.

```
update  g 
set     g.Ebat=mtib.icerik_anlami  
from    #gecici g
inner join database.dbo.table2 mtib on mtib.malzeme_kodu=g.malzeme_kodu
    and mtib.alan_sabit_adi='ebat' 
    and g.Ebat=mtib.icerik
```

Comment: time did not notice

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing this as a single query:

```
update g
    set Ebat = (case when mtib.alan_sabit_adi = 'ebat' and g.Ebat = mtib.icerikmtib.icerik_anlami
                     then mtib.icerik_anlami else g.Ebat
                end),
         zemin_rengi = (case when mtib.alan_sabit_adi = 'ZeminRengi' and ga.zemin_rengi = mtib.icerik
                             then mtib.sira_no else g.zemin_rengi
                        end),
         bordur_rengi = mtib.sira_no
    from #gecici g join
         database.dbo.table2 mtib
         on mtib.malzeme_kodu = g.malzeme_kodu;
```

Combining the queries prevents updating the same row multiple times.

The `inner join` versus `outer join` only makes a difference on the third query, because that will update all rows.  I am guessing that is not what you want.

Then you want an index on `database.dbo.table2(malzeme_kodu)`.  You can include all the other columns in the query in the index.

Comment: tried but gave incorrect result